# how to modify for loop that will run over next few days instead of just one

Tags: python, loops, timestamp

I have the following code working, but at the moment is giving me the exact date match only.
What I need is to get the match on the exact date from party dataframe plus 3 next days.

sample of columns from two datasets

1. Party
2. Event:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
event = []


for date in party['date']:
       event.append(date in travel['date'].unique())

event = pd.Series(event)
```

Output is True or False if there is match or not.

I need to find the match of travel date with range of dates from party (date + 3 days).

How to modify that loop to run through party['date'] + 3 next following days.

Comment: Not seeing the data itself makes answering this question harder. Just from this information I'd say you somewhere have to add 3 days to your date so the comparison works for the next _3_ days.

Comment: the 'party' data frame contains 'date' feature - datetime64 dtype and the 'travel' data frame contains feature 'date' - datetime64 dtype. The other features are not involved in the code here.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution to my problem, (I am sorry if my problem description wasn't clear):

```
event = []

for date in party['date']:
    event.append(date in travel['date'].unique() 
                     or date + timedelta(days=1) in travel['date'].unique()
                     or date + timedelta(days=2) in travel['date'].unique()
                     or date + timedelta(days=3) in travel['date'].unique())


event = pd.Series(event)
```